# multicharacter delimited data to be read into dataframe without quotes in python

Tags: python, pandas

I Have a csv file in which columns are delimited by |@|. And column values are enclosed in double quotes. When reading the data using pandas, double quotes are also being read into dataframe. But I dont need enclosed quotes to be read.

This is how my data looks.

```
"col1"|@|"col2"|@|"col3"
"abcd"|@|"gd"ft"|@|"sdddddd"
"iob"|@|"gtyu"|@|"uiui"uo"
```

When i am reading the data using pandas, this is how the data is being read.

```
df=pd.read_csv(input_file,sep='\|\@\|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

   "col1"   "col2"     "col3"
0  "abcd"  "gd"ft"  "sdddddd"
1   "iob"   "gtyu"  "uiui"uo"
```

But i need this data to be read without quotes.
This is how i need output

```
   col1   col2     col3
0  abcd  gd"ft  sdddddd
1   iob   gtyu  uiui"uo
```

I tried by giving quoting=3,skipinitialspace=True but its not ignoring quotes.
Can someone help me.

Comment: If it is just one file, you could also use just `find and replace` option to eliminate double quotes

Comment: @sai suppose i am having one free text field and data of the column may have double quotes, in that case what can i do?

Comment: df.appy will work for your problem. If it works, upvote my answer

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but since the delimiter would still be present, that particular cell i.e., element would/should probably reflect as empty string while reading using pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```py
df.columns = [x.replace('"', '') for x in df.columns]  # to replace quotes in column labels
 
# have to update here, had missed df =
df = df.replace(to_replace=r"^\"|\"$",value='',regex=True)  # to replace quotes in cells
```

I get this as output

```
   col1   col2     col3
0  abcd  gd"ft  sdddddd
1   iob   gtyu  uiui"uo
```

Comment: I tried this, but enclosed quotes in data is not getting replaced.

Comment: i do not understand, do you mean to get rid of the double quote in **gd"ft**?

Comment: No outside quotes. Only outside quotes of Column names gone but not the data ones.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. just a second

Comment: @Jennie check the solution now

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is a little big gun for your needs, but you can wrap the input file and modify it on the fly before it gets into pandas csv_reader, this gives you opportunity to add as many regexes or other modifiers as you need.

```py
import io
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd

filedata = io.BytesIO(b"""
"col1"|@|"col2"|@|"col3"
"abcd"|@|"gd"ft"|@|"sdddddd"
"iob"|@|"gtyu"|@|"uiui"uo"
""")

class Wrapper(io.TextIOWrapper):
    MODIFIERS = [
        (re.compile(r'^"'), ''),
        (re.compile(r'"$'), ''),
        (re.compile(r'"\|\@\|"'), '|@|'),
    ]
    def readline(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dataline = super().readline(*args, **kwargs)
        for regex, change_to in self.MODIFIERS:
            dataline = regex.sub(change_to, dataline)
        return dataline

input_file = Wrapper(filedata)
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep=r'\|\@\|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
print(df)
```

for reading from txt file use code below instead BytesIO object

```py
with open('filedata.txt', 'rb') as filedata:
    input_file = Wrapper(filedata)
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep=r'\|\@\|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
print(df)
```

and output

```
   col1   col2     col3
0  abcd  gd"ft  sdddddd
1   iob   gtyu  uiui"uo
```

Comment: Let’s say, I have data in txt file. So how do I need to read to filedata variable.

Comment: @jennie added block with reading directly from file (code starting with  `with open(...)`)